# How do I mine blocks with Python?

Tags: mining, python

I don't know how to mine blocks with Python.
Can I mine blocks with *Pyethapp*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used it myself, so others may want to comment further.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/blob/develop/README.rst), `pyethapp` is composed of `pythereum` and `pydevp2p`, the former of which:

> pyethereum - the core library, featuring the blockchain, the ethereum
>   virtual machine, **mining**

So in answer to your question:

> Can I mine blocks with Pyethapp?

I'd say the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to an Alpha-level project still in active development, then you might also be interested in [py-evm](https://github.com/pipermerriam/py-evm/).

> Py-EVM is a new implementation of the Ethereum Virtual Machine written in python. It is currently in active development but is quickly progressing through the test suite provided by ethereum/tests ... Development will focus on creating an EVM with a well defined API, friendly and easy to digest documentation which can be run as a fully functional mainnet node.